# Flutter : How to add a listener that will do something whenever the data is changed in Cloud Firestore Database?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm a newbie in Flutter and Cloud Firestore. So far I've got hold of using basic 'get' and 'post' requests. I'm using cloud firestore in my flutter project currently and my goal is to auto refresh the page whenever a certain document or collection data is changed. Hence I was curious about how can I add a listener to the database which will notify the app whenever there is a change in the database. Thanks in advance for answering.

I followed the answer provided by @Frank Van Puffelen (One with a green tick) and it worked perfectly.

Note :

1. Before doing this make sure you have a proper internet connection.
2. If you are using a virtual device (Android Emulator), it might not work properly.Instead as soon as you update the database, it will give an error like this :
   " [{0}] Failed to resolve name. status={1} "
   In this case its the issue of the virtual device and not your code. You need to restart your virtual device to see the changes or you can test your code on a physical device where it will reflect immediately as soon as you make changes in the database.

Comment: There is a lot of documentation that describes the APIs.  I suggest starting there, an addition to anything you find with a web search.  If you have a specific question regarding the APIs, or if something is not working the way you expect, please post that in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`cloud_firestore` plugin package](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore) has a great [example of how to use it](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore#-example-tab-), which shows precisely how to do this.

The relevant code for what you're asking:

```
  final Firestore firestore;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: firestore
          .collection("messages")
          .orderBy("created_at", descending: true)
          .snapshots(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) return const Text('Loading...');
        final int messageCount = snapshot.data.documents.length;
        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: messageCount,
          itemBuilder: (_, int index) {
            final DocumentSnapshot document = snapshot.data.documents[index];
            final dynamic message = document['message'];
            return ListTile(
              trailing: IconButton(
                onPressed: () => document.reference.delete(),
                icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
              ),
              title: Text(
                message != null ? message.toString() : '<No message retrieved>',
              ),
              subtitle: Text('Message ${index + 1} of $messageCount'),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: Hello again ....... just had a doubt. ......... Does re-using a document snapshot consumes a read in case of firestore ?

Comment: And another doubt > ............ I am using a setState function in the page I have implemented the above code. The issue is that the stream is being called twice after the setState is executed. I also made sure that the page is only being refreshed once on setState ....... but then why is the stream called twice ?

Comment: Please don't post additional questions in comments, as it's hard to keep helping that way. But: 1) Reading data from an existing `DocumentSnapshot` multiple times does not lead to multiple charges, 2) sounds like worth of a new question, as it's hard to say what's going on from just a description.